# How to load text file into pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, read.csv

i have a text file 
sample:

----------NEW TRANSACTON----------- 
TRANSACTION DATE : 08:42 AM, 30 Nov 2021 
CLIENT ID : C00001 
CLIENT NAME : SALISU BISI 
AMOUNT : 16,450.00 
TRANSACTION REF. : 00001

----------NEW TRANSACTON----------- 
TRANSACTION DATE : 08:46 AM, 30 Nov 2021 
CLIENT ID : C00002 
CLIENT NAME : SULE YAYA 
AMOUNT : 80,940.00 
TRANSACTION REF. : 00002

----------NEW TRANSACTON----------- 
TRANSACTION DATE : 08:51 AM, 30 Nov 2021 
CLIENT ID : C00001 
CLIENT NAME : SALISU BISI 
AMOUNT : 44,900.00 
TRANSACTION REF. : 00003

how do i load it into pandas? 
i tried 
 `df=pd.read_csv("2021_11_30.txt", delimiter="\t")
df` 

but it loaded it in one column

Answer (score 0):

it will load as one column, because that is what a text file is.

what you are in fact asking is *how to identify and split the lines correctly into multiple columns*.

you could do this with pandas in a roundabout way, but with unstructured text data like this, it would be better to either:

- read a properly formatted csv with `pandas`
- read a file line-by-line into a list

reading into a list is covered here:
[How to read a file line-by-line into a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277503/how-to-read-a-file-line-by-line-into-a-list)

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
with open(file, 'r') as rf:
     str_file = rf.read()
first_replace = str_file.replace('----------NEW TRANSACTON-----------','')
spliting_str = first_replace.split('\n\n\n')
clean_list = [tuple(r.split(':',1)) for row in spliting_str for r in row.split('\n') if r != '']
for k,v in clean_list:
    d[k].append(v)
```

Now you have a dict of lists that you can load into a dataframe:

```
df =pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

without extra import, replace, with less for and if.

```
with open("/path/to/file.txt", "r") as f:
    l = f.readlines()
d = {}
for idx, el in enumerate(l):
    if "----------NEW TRANSACTON-----------" in el:
        for i in range(1,5):
            k, v = l[idx+i].strip().split(" : ")
            if k not in d.keys():
                d[k] = [v]
            else:
                d[k].append(v)
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d)
```

Comment: thanks, i am just starting out learning python(pandas) and this helped alot!